# How to add months to a date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to add months to a date in JavaScript.

For example: I am inserting date `06/01/2011` (format `mm/dd/yyyy`) and now I want to add 8 months to this date. I want the result to be `02/01/2012`.

So when adding months, the year may also increase.

Comment: If, you add 8 months to the date 06/01/2011 how it will be changed to 02/01/2011, Please can you make it some what clear

Comment: this is a hard problem to get right - what happens if you're on the 31st of a month and the target month doesn't have 31 days?  Even worse, what if the target month is February?

Comment: @kalyan : if I add 8 months to the date 06/01/2011(mm/dd/yyyy) then it will be 02/01/2012 because if we add 06+08 = 14 and we have only 12 months so it will change the year and give the result as 02/01/2012.

Comment: @Alnitak : No dear it will only start with 1st date of month.

Comment: then you should have said so....

Comment: I suggest adding days instead of months. if you add one month to 30.01.2011 what would the result be? 30.02.2011 ? 02.03.2011 ?

Comment: @Alnitak : I have already maintain that in the my question...

Comment: no, you didn't.  The fact that the dates in your question are all the 1st would be taken by most as an _example_, and not a _constraint_.  You even said so: "For example:".

Comment: var month = new Date(someDate).getMonth() + 1;

Comment: Just encountered this issue today, in case the day of the date is between 1 - 28 (where we know for sure the next month has these days) you can just use `setMonth(currentMonth + 1)`, else use Luxon or any other `Date` replacement because it won't work otherwise (unless you do parsing on the backend, because JS zero-month based dates is going to screw you)

Answer (score 490, accepted):

**Corrected as of 25.06.2019:**

```
var newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+8));
```

**Old**
From [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/01/07/javascript-add-a-month-to-a-date/):

```
var jan312009 = new Date(2009, 0, 31);
var eightMonthsFromJan312009  = jan312009.setMonth(jan312009.getMonth()+8);
```

Comment: that's not a typo - the Date constructor uses 0 for January, not 1.

Comment: What if for example you add 1 instead of 8?  It would display February 31st 2009 would it not?

Comment: @Sampson. No, it will display March 3rd 2009 :)

Comment: Check this solution for last days in month ;)

Comment: Why do you have to do `new Date` on `jan3120091` twice? Couldn't the second line be `var eight.... = jan312009.setMonth(jan312009.getMonth()+8);`?

Comment: the setMonth() method mutates the date it's called on so surely you need to do the following to not change jan312009
var jan312009 = new Date(2009, 0, 31);
var eightMonthsFromJan312009 = new Date(jan312009.getTime());
eightMonthsFromJan312009.setMonth(jan312009.getMonth()+8);

Comment: running this code in a REPL sets `eightMonthsFromJan312009` to a number, not a valid date.  Calling `jan312009.setMonth(jan312009.getMonth()+8);` changes the variable `jan312009` rather than returning the expected value.

Comment: To run it in REPL one needs to remove var before the declaration of variables.

Comment: no you don't.. if you use http://repl.it  it just takes pure Javascript like what you've pasted.  Try it.. see the results.

Comment: This is really not a reusable solution since setMonth can only accept values from 0-11. So you can't add 8 month to April.

Comment: OP, please change your answer : as @tazmaniax and other people said, the `setMonth()` method does not return a `Date` object, it returns a `Number` representative of the unix timestamp (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp)
Therefore, the acceptable answers would be to either remove the new var assignation, or instance a new Date object using the returned timestamp : 
`var newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+8))`

Comment: It's important to emphasize that both `date` and `newDate` will contain the same date after this code is run. IOW `date` is modified by this code.

Comment: @VinayakThatte it seems that it accepts more than that, please check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth).
monthValue: A zero-based integer representing the month of the year offset from the start of the year. So, 0 represents January, 11 represents December, -1 represents December of the previous year, and 12 represents January of the following year.

Comment: error "date" as shown in lowercase is nothing in JS

Comment: adding 1 month to 31 of January dives you 3 March is it OK?

Comment: Gives Invalid date error when the added months sum to > 12

Answer (score 131):

I took a look at the datejs and stripped out the code necessary to add months to a date handling edge cases (leap year, shorter months, etc):

```
Date.isLeapYear = function (year) { 
    return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0)); 
};

Date.getDaysInMonth = function (year, month) {
    return [31, (Date.isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
};

Date.prototype.isLeapYear = function () { 
    return Date.isLeapYear(this.getFullYear()); 
};

Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth = function () { 
    return Date.getDaysInMonth(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth());
};

Date.prototype.addMonths = function (value) {
    var n = this.getDate();
    this.setDate(1);
    this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + value);
    this.setDate(Math.min(n, this.getDaysInMonth()));
    return this;
};
```

This will add "addMonths()" function to any javascript date object that should handle edge cases. Thanks to Coolite Inc!

Use:

```
var myDate = new Date("01/31/2012");
var result1 = myDate.addMonths(1);

var myDate2 = new Date("01/31/2011");
var result2 = myDate2.addMonths(1);
```

->>  newDate.addMonths -> mydate.addMonths

result1 = "Feb 29 2012"

result2 = "Feb 28 2011"

Comment: Is this the only solution that considers for example this: 
Oct 31 2011 + 1 ?

Comment: easier IMHO finding days in month is return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate(); So also the need for isLeapYear() falls. Also not clear the need for not-Prototype-Methods

Comment: Interesting Daniel that you can put a 0 day to get the previous month.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/nikoudel/mdzaddeh/
Suppose initial date is "2011-03-11T00:00:00Z" and local timezone is Helsinki (GMT+2). When adding six months, an hour gets lost because of daylight savings time: Sat, 10 Sep 2011 23:00:00 GMT.

Comment: See [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36331522/513570) when a non extending prototype solution is needed, as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 19):

I would highly recommend taking a look at [datejs](http://datejs.com). With it's api, it becomes drop dead simple to add a month (and lots of other date functionality):

```
var one_month_from_your_date = your_date_object.add(1).month();
```

What's nice about `datejs` is that it handles edge cases, because technically you can do this using the native `Date` object and it's attached methods. But you end up pulling your hair out over edge cases, which `datejs` has taken care of for you.

Plus it's open source!