# date manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datediff

Suppose I get a date via a jquery calendar to a java script variable.
e.g: var d = 02/12/2011

How can I manipulate that date variable using a js function or jq method where to get the date 3 month ahead of that date? I cant just do following know. Because every month does not have 30 days?

```
var futureDate=new Date(d);
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate()+30*3);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add months in javascript date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-in-javascript-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using either the [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) libraries. They both have great date manipulation functions.

Here's an example using Sugar...

```
var futureDate = Date.create(d);
futureDate.addMonths(3);
```

The value d can be anything that [Sugar understands as a date](http://sugarjs.com/dates) which is quite flexible.

Comment: Agreed. In fact @Chetan has a good answer for this simple problem. I just thought I would give a plug for some great date/time libraries that can help improve date manipulation, especially if you accept user entered dates (they both have great date parsing).

Answer (score 3):

Use `futureDate.setMonth(futureDate.getMonth() + 3)`

This will work towards the end of the year too. It roll over to the new year automatically.

Comment: I'm interested in the reason for this downvote, since it's the same answer that got the checkmark here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-in-javascript-date

Comment: thanks Chetan..suppose its 1 year and 4 days something like that..then how its done pls

Comment: Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Chetan: above does not work for edge cases. See below, http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/01/07/javascript-add-a-month-to-a-date/  I have go ahead with Datejs which is pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good routine that can handle that and lots of other date manipulations:

http://slingfive.com/pages/code/jsDate/jsDate.html