# Arrows to switch the month in a calendar app

Tags: javascript, html, button

I would like to develop a calendar using javascript and i don't know how to approach the situation, i mean i would like to use 2 arrows ( one to the left , one to the right ) to switch the month and the year for which the days are displayed. How do i do that when the right arrow is pressed to switch to the next month and so on ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-in-javascript-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back I modified the [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to support this kind of thing. I don't have the source up on git or anything so here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUrJY/2/

[image]

The relevant portion of the change is in the `_generateHTML` method.

```
var prev = (this._canAdjustMonth(inst, -1, drawYear, drawMonth) ?
'<a style="left: 22px;" class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_' + dpuuid +
'.datepicker._adjustDate(\'#' + inst.id + '\', -' + stepMonths + ', \'M\');"' +
' title="' + prevText + '"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-' + (isRTL ? 'e' : 'w') + '">' + prevText + '</span></a>' :
(hideIfNoPrevNext ? '' : '<a style="left: 22px;" class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" title="' + prevText + '"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-' + (isRTL ? 'e' : 'w') + '">' + prevText + '</span></a>'));

prev += (this._canAdjustMonth(inst, -12, drawYear, drawMonth) ?
'<a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_' + dpuuid +
'.datepicker._adjustDate(\'#' + inst.id + '\', -' + 12 + ', \'M\');"' +
' title="Prev Year"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-' + (isRTL ? 'e' : 'w') + '">Prev Year</span></a>' :
(hideIfNoPrevNext ? '' : '<a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" title="Prev Year"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-' + (isRTL ? 'e' : 'w') + '">' + prevText + '</span></a>'));

var nextText = this._get(inst, 'nextText');
nextText = (!navigationAsDateFormat ? nextText : this.formatDate(nextText,
this._daylightSavingAdjust(new Date(drawYear, drawMonth + stepMonths, 1)),
this._getFormatConfig(inst)));
var next = (this._canAdjustMonth(inst, +1, drawYear, drawMonth) ?
'<a style="right: 22px;" class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_' + dpuuid +
'.datepicker._adjustDate(\'#' + inst.id + '\', +' + stepMonths + ', \'M\');"' +
' title="' + nextText + '"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-' + (isRTL ? 'w' : 'e') + '">' + nextText + '</span></a>' :
(hideIfNoPrevNext ? '' : '<a style="right: 22px;" class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" title="' + nextText + '"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-' + (isRTL ? 'w' : 'e') + '">' + nextText + '</span></a>'));

next += (this._canAdjustMonth(inst, +1, drawYear, drawMonth) ?
'<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_' + dpuuid +
'.datepicker._adjustDate(\'#' + inst.id + '\', +' + 12 + ', \'M\');"' +
' title="Next Year"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-' + (isRTL ? 'w' : 'e') + '">Next Year</span></a>' :
(hideIfNoPrevNext ? '' : '<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" title="Next Year"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-' + (isRTL ? 'w' : 'e') + '">' + nextText + '</span></a>'));
```