# What is the source of this off-by-one error in a JavaScript date?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to write a function that will take a string like `07/2020` and then return whether it is more than three months away.

I have written a function `isMoreThan3MonthsHence` that I am reasonably sure works correctly:

```js
const isMoreThan3MonthsHence = ({ utcYear, utcMonth }, 
                                now = new Date, 
                                target = new Date(Date.UTC(utcYear, utcMonth)), 
                                threeMonthsAway = new Date(now.valueOf()).setUTCMonth(now.getUTCMonth() + 3)) => 
    (target > threeMonthsAway)


console.log(isMoreThan3MonthsHence({ utcYear: 2020, utcMonth: 7 })) // true (correct!)
```

The problem comes when I try to construct a `Date` object to use to populate the arguments for `isMoreThan3MonthsHence`.

```js
const validate = (str, 
                  [localMonth, localYear] = str.split('/'), 
                  date = new Date(+localYear, (+localMonth)-1)) => 
    isMoreThan3MonthsHence({ utcYear: date.getUTCFullYear(), utcMonth: date.getUTCMonth() })

// Note: input is one-based months
console.log(validate('07/2020')) // false (but should be true!)
```

I think the reason is that new-ing up a `Date` in `validate` without specifying the timezone will use the local timezone in effect at the supplied date, which will be BST (UTC+1).

```
Wed Jul 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

This time is actually 2300hrs on **June** 30th in UTC. So the month is actually `5` in zero-based terms. But I don't want this behavior. I want it so specifying July actually means July in UTC.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps because `Date.UTC()` treats your arguments as UTC, while `new Date()` treats them as local (UTC+1) and once you're calling `getUTCMonth()` you're indeed an hour earlier from UTC perspective (then still in the previous month). Why not use `Date.UTC()` in both?

Comment: Do `new Date(2020, 6).toUTCString()` - i.e. looking at the entire date, not just month and year - and you will clearly see why. Yes, it does have to do with the fact that you're in BST in July.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than mixing UTC and local dates, the way you're adding 3 months will cause an incorrect response for dates like 31 March, where adding 3 months simply by incrementing the month number results in a date for 1 July.  See [Adding months to a Date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793045/adding-months-to-a-date-in-javascript).

So `validate('07,2020')` will return false if run on  31 March.

To fix that, when adding months, check that the updated date is still on the same day in the month, otherwise it's rolled over so set it to the last day of the previous month.

```js
function validate(s) {
  let testDate = addMonths(new Date(), 3);
  let [m, y] = s.split(/\D/);
  return testDate < new Date(y, m-1);
};

function addMonths(date, months) {
  let d = date.getDate();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + +months);
  // If rolled over to next month, set to last day of previous month
  if (date.getDate() != d) {
    date.setDate(0);
  }
  return date;
}

// Sample
console.log('On ' + new Date().toDateString() + ':');
['07/2020', '04/2020'].forEach(
  s => console.log(s + ' - ' + validate(s))
);
```

Comment: The top answer in the linked question is highly misleading. Are you willing to edit it to be more accurate?

Comment: @ben—changed linked answer to a better one.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have gone in and edited originally-linked answer. It was highly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing the usage of `Date.UTC` and not when instantiating dates.  For example, if you use the following for your validate function:

```
const validate = (str, 
                  [month, year] = str.split('/'), 
                  date = new Date(Date.UTC(+year, (+month)-1))) => 
    isMoreThan3MonthsHence({ utcYear: date.getUTCFullYear(), utcMonth: date.getUTCMonth() })

// Note: input is one-based months
console.log(validate('07/2020')) // Now true
```

It works as expected: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm437ze2/2/)

Removing the usage of `Date.UTC` altogether would perform the calculation in the user's local timezone, with any applicable daylight saving adjustment included.  This *could* be seen as a valid approach, however would result in the behaviour you have described.

---

Note I've renamed the `local` prefixed variables based on feedback from Bergi.  Using `Date.UTC` implies you're passing in UTC arguments.