# How can I set the date from one date input to another date input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input

I have two date inputs. When I choose start date, I want jquery to automatically generate an end date that's 3 months later.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Start Date</label>
    <input type="date" id="darbo_pradzia" name="darbo_pradzia" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">End date </label>
    <input type="date" id="bandomasis_laikotarpis" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to `change` events of the first input and create a `new Date` with its value. After that, you can add 3 months to this object using `new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+3))`. The new date with the extra 3 months should be formatted into `yyyy-mm-dd` and set to the value of the second input. The complete program is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#darbo_pradzia').change(function(){
          let date = new Date($(this).val());
          let newDate = addMonths(date, 3);
          var formatted = newDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]; //yyyy-mm-dd
          console.log(formatted);
          $('#bandomasis_laikotarpis').val(formatted);
     });
     //add months to date function
     function addMonths(date, months) {
          var d = date.getDate();
          date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + +months);
          if (date.getDate() != d) {
               date.setDate(0);
          }
          return date;
     }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Start Date</label>
          <input type="date" id="darbo_pradzia" name="darbo_pradzia" class="form-control">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">End date </label>
          <input type="date" id="bandomasis_laikotarpis" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis" class="form-control">
     </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**
According to @[RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg)'s comment, adding a number of months to a date object has several unique test cases that need to be taken into consideration. Therefore, I used his answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793045/adding-months-to-a-date-in-javascript/12793246#12793246) to achieve this operation.

Comment: Adding months is not that simple, see [Adding months to a Date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793045/adding-months-to-a-date-in-javascript/12793246#12793246). E.g. try adding 3 months to 30 November or 31 March.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $('#darbo_pradzia').on('focusout', function(){
    let startDate = new Date($('#darbo_pradzia').val());
    let endDate = new Date(startDate);
    endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth()+3);

   let day = ("0" + endDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
   let month = ("0" + (endDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   let date = endDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

$('#bandomasis_laikotarpis').val(date);
   })
</script>
```

You can read the value on the `onchange` event or `focusout` event. Read the date and you can copy the inserted date from the `Date` constructor. Increase the month, no problem if you overflow the 12 months because automatically the year is increased and the month value scaled between [0-11].  Now to write the date in the input date field there are two problem:

Date control in HTML 5 accepts in the format of Year - month - day

If the month is 5, it needs to be set as 05 not 5 simply. The same thing for day field also.

Add the script downwards in the page, or add a ready/onload event