# Disable next 1 month MonthPicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to disable till Next 1 month. please help me out

```
$(".input-monthpicker-freezelastyear").datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
        startDate: new Date(),
        autoclose: true
    });
```

my code look like this

Comment: Meaning that you want to increase the `startDate` by one month? Or show the date from _"today"_ but not allow the user to click them? Which may be an annoying UX

Comment: i will go with startdate by 1 month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push the date by 1 whole month you could do something like this:

```js
// Get Date now
const date = new Date()
// Set the month exactly one more from now
date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1)

console.log(date);
```

Or wrap it into a function to use elswhere like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date) ([answer's source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793045/adding-months-to-a-date-in-javascript/12793246#12793246))

Comment: startDate: date,   i used like this.. is it crrt way  ?? date contain your code implementation

Comment: tq i got solution with your help. tq