# javascript add X number of months to date keeping the day number

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add months to a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript)

What's the simplest way to add X numbers of months to a date object but keep the day number? My date's will always be the first of the month.

Examples:
If my start date is "04/01/2012" and i need to add 4 months to it, the result will be "08/01/2012".

If my start date is "10/01/2012" and i need to add 4 months to it, the result will be "02/01/2013".

Comment: Have you checked out the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like `date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+4)`. This will automatically catch the overflow condition and add one to the Year.

Comment: thanks. i knew i was over thinking that