# javascript add month to date

Tags: javascript

I want to add 1 Month or 6 Month to a given Date.
But if i add one Month, the year isnt incremented. And if i add 6 Month to June, i got the Month 00 returned BUT the year is incremented.
Could you please help me out?

```
function addToBis(monthToAdd){
        var tmp = $("#terminbis").val().split('.');

        var day = tmp[0];
        var month = tmp[1];
        var year = tmp[2];

        var terminDate = new Date(parseInt(year),parseInt(month), parseInt(day));
        terminDate.setMonth(terminDate.getMonth()+monthToAdd);

        day = "";
        month = "";
        year = "";

        if(terminDate.getDate() < 10){
            day = "0"+terminDate.getDate();
        } else{
            day = terminDate.getDate();
        }

        if(terminDate.getMonth() < 10){
            month = "0"+terminDate.getMonth();
        } else{
            month = terminDate.getMonth();
        }

        year = terminDate.getFullYear();


        $("#terminbis").val(day+"."+month+"."+year);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried increasing the month value inside the new Date() call?

`var terminDate = new Date(parseInt(year),parseInt(month)+monthToAdd, parseInt(day));`

Comment: check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Refactored version with the months fixed in case you'd find it useful http://jsfiddle.net/LRA7d/2/

Comment: There is no need for `parseInt(year)`, `parseInt(month)`, etc. Given that the radix is omitted in each case, it's far better to use plain `year`, `month`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getMonth returns a number from 0 to 11 which means 0 for January , 1 for february ...etc

so modify like this

```
var terminDate = new Date(parseInt(year),parseInt(month - 1), parseInt(day));
    terminDate.setMonth(terminDate.getMonth()+monthToAdd);
```

and

```
month = terminDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

Comment: Yes I see, this will show december as 12 instead of 0. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should use the javascript Date object's native methods to update it. Check out this question's accepted answer for example, it is the correct approach to your problem.

[Javascript function to add X months to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0):

The function can be written much more concisely as:

```
function addToBis(monthToAdd){

    function z(n) {return (n<10? '0':'') + n}

    var tmp = $("#terminbis").val().split('.');
    var d = new Date(tmp[2], --tmp[1], tmp[0]);

    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + monthToAdd);

    $("#terminbis").val(z(d.getDate()) + '.' + z(d.getMonth() + 1)
                       + '.' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

The value of `terminbis` and `monthToAdd` should be validated before use, as should the date generated from the value.