# How to match two integer arrays, so the smallest one expands to closest neighbour from larger one

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer, match, expand

Let's say I have two array pairs:

```
let a1 = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000],
    b1 = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000];
```

and

```
let a2 = [10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000],
    b2 = [10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000];
```

or any arbitrary pair of integers.

The task is to expand the smallest array in the pair to largest size in this way, keeping smallest domain the same as well as values:

```
b1 =          [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000];
expanded_a1 = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 12000];

a2 =          [10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000]
expanded_b2 = [10000, 20000, 20000, 30000, 30000, 40000, 40000, 50000, 50000, 60000];

invalid_expanded_b2 = [10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 30000, 40000, 40000, 50000, 50000, 60000];

//second value is invalid
```

And once again, example with the third pair:

```
let a3 = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35];
let b3 = [10, 20, 30];
```

So, expanded b3 should have only 10,20,30 values and its domain have to be [10,30]

```
              [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
                ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
expanded_b3 = [10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30]
```

Pretty sure, that, first of all, I need to clone the largest array and go through its every element and compare it with integers from the smallest array and if values don't match replace it with the closest left (or if there is no such, the right) integer from the smallest array.

Comment: This is usually called *interpolation* - when you know value `a` and value `c` but need to find value `b` which is between them. Especially when you have a monotonous sequence or can create some inference rule for what the missing data would look like. I can't find something about interpolating missing numbers from parallel series but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283213/how-to-interpolate-missing-dates-and-data-points-in-javascript-arrays) is something somewhat related.

Comment: Wait, I think I misread the question. I thought you wanted to generate a new number where it's missing and it'd be based on its neighbours and the parallel array. But you just want to double an existing number.

Comment: Yes, I have updated question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems tricky to do at first but it's actually not that hard. You just have to go through both arrays together. Think of it as getting two pointers and then moving them along:

```
a2 =      [10000, 15000, 20000]
           ^^^^^
             |
pointer 1 ----

b2 =      [10000, 20000]
           ^^^^^
             |
pointer 2 ----
```

- If the current value assigned to each pointer is equal, then you have a match - just return the value and move both pointers

```
a2 =      [10000, 15000, 20000]
                  ^^^^^
                    |
pointer 1 -----------

b2 =      [10000, 20000]
                  ^^^^^
                    |
pointer 2 -----------
```

- If the current values don't match, then only advance the pointer belonging to the longer array but return the value from the shorter

```
a2 =      [10000, 15000, 20000]
                         ^^^^^
                           |
pointer 1 ------------------

b2 =      [10000, 20000]
                  ^^^^^
                    |
pointer 2 -----------
```

Repeat until you finish the longer array.

You can do this in `O(n)` time.

Here is an implementation using a [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and the ES6 array [Iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) to walk both arrays. It is slightly more convenient than using pointers, since you can directly generate an array using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let a1 = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000],
    b1 = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000];
    
let a2 = [10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000],
    b2 = [10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000];
    
function equaliseLength(arr1, arr2) {
  //equal length, nothing to do, just return
  if (arr1.length === arr2.length) return;
  
  //setup what to work with
  let longerArray;
  let arrayToExpand;
  
  if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    longerArray = arr1;
    arrayToExpand = arr2;
  } else {
    longerArray = arr2;
    arrayToExpand = arr1;
  }
  
  const generator = generateMissingSlots(arrayToExpand, longerArray);
  
  //convert to array
  const result = Array.from(generator);
  
  return result;
}

function* generateMissingSlots(shorter, longer) {
  //start two iterators for each array
  const shortIterator = shorter[Symbol.iterator]();
  const longIterator = longer[Symbol.iterator]();
  
  //get the initial values
  let shortCurrent = shortIterator.next();
  let longCurrent = longIterator.next();
  
  let lastShortValue = shortCurrent.value;
  
  //go through both until the longer is exhausted
  while(!longCurrent.done) {
    //produce the current value of the shorter array
    yield lastShortValue;
    
    //only advance the short iterator if the two have "caught up" 
    if (shortCurrent.value === longCurrent.value){
      shortCurrent = shortIterator.next();
      
      //update the value unless the iterator is exhausted
      //in case of `short = [a, b]` and `long = [a, b, c]` which will produce `undefined` for the last values
      if(!shortCurrent.done) {
        lastShortValue = shortCurrent.value
      }
    }
    
    //always advance the long iterator
    longCurrent = longIterator.next();
  }
}

expanded_a1 = equaliseLength(a1, b1);
console.log(expanded_a1);

expanded_b2 = equaliseLength(a2, b2);
console.log(expanded_b2);
```

Comment: Cheers, that's very close to what I have proposed but more organized

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but something like this clumsy solution.

```js
Number.prototype.between = function (domain_) {

     var min = Math.min.apply(Math, domain_);
     var max = Math.max.apply(Math, domain_);

     return this >= min && this <= max;

   };
      
  let a1 = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000];
  let b1 = [2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000];
      
  let result = matchArrays(a1, b1); 
  console.log(result);

  let a2 = [10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000];
  let b2 = [10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000];

  result = matchArrays(a2, b2); 
  console.log(result)
  
 function matchArrays(a_, b_){
      
      if(a_.length == b_.length) { return [a_, b_]; }
      else if(a_.length > b_.length){
          
          if(a_.length - b_.length == 1) { b_.push(b_[b_.length - 1]); return [a_, b_]; }
 
          let b2 = a_.slice(0, a_.length);
          b2.forEach((d_, i_) => { 
          
              for(let i = 1; i < b_.length; i++){
                  
                  if(d_ != b_[i - 1] && d_ != b_[i] && d_.between([b_[i - 1], b_[i]])){
                    
                     b2[i_] = b_[i];
                      
                  }
                  
                  if(d_ > b_[b_.length - 1]) { b2[i_] = b_[b_.length - 1] }
                  
              }

          
          });
          
          return [a_, b2]
          
      }
      else{
          
          if(b_.length - a_.length == 1) { a_.push(a_[a_.length - 1]); return [a_, b_]; }
          let a2 = b_.slice(0, b_.length);
          
          a2.forEach((d_, i_) => { 
          
              for(let i = 1; i < a_.length; i++){
                  
                  if(d_ != a_[i - 1] && d_ != a_[i] && d_.between([a_[i - 1], a_[i]])){
                      
                     a2[i_] = a_[i];
                      
                  }
                  
              }
              
              if(d_ > a_[a_.length - 1]) { a2[i_] = a_[a_.length - 1] }
          
          });
          
          return [a2, b_]
          
      }
      
  }
```