# adding three months to the current month in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used the following Javascript code to get the current year.

```
new Date().getFullYear()
```

what I want is to add three months to the current date and check whether the year changes! In java we can make this happen but I don't know how to do this javascript. How can I check this condition with javascript!

Comment: Look for accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript and just adjust number of months to be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var n1 = new Date().getFullYear();

var presentDate= new Date();
presentDate.setMonth(presentDate.getMonth()+No Of months you want to add);

var n2 = presentDate.getFullYear();

 if(n1 == n2)
    alert("Year not changed");
   else
    alert("Year changed");
```

Comment: @Juhana sorry if my view is wrong

Comment: Why downvote.Please give me the reason

Comment: Please learn to give comment before giving a downvote

Comment: @downvoter: can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

to shift a date object to 3 months forward you can use the [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) function.

```
var k = new Date();

k.setMonth(k.getMonth()+3);

alert(k);
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/NwdAz/).