# Add X months to a javascript date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following design and I want to add six months to the start date on On-blur event but my code returns the finish date in millisecond format.

```
    function calDate() {
    var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('txtstdate').value);
    document.getElementById("txtenddate").value = date1.setDate(date1.getDate()+30);
```

**Current Design:-**

 [image]

Comment: This the code i have written to add 30 days to current date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function to add X months to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
function calDate() {
    var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('txtstdate').value);
    document.getElementById("txtenddate").value = parseInt(date1.getDate()) + 30;
}
```

Comment: I just changed it to add as an Int instead of a string. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) function here.

Use this as a reference: [How to add months to a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript)