# javascript add number of months to specific date format

Tags: javascript, date

My current date format is `30-Dec-2018`. I want to add 2 month (might change) to this date format so my output will be 28-Feb-2019. I have given few tries to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript) but haven't succeeded.

I think my date format is causing issue in generating correct output. Any help in adding a month to the above mentioned date format in javascript. Thanks

P.S: Adding date might change the year as well

EDIT:

```
var date= new Date(30-Dec-2018);
var month_add  = date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+2);
    alert(month_add);
```

output I am getting in alertbox is: 1553022000000

Comment: the format need not be an issue. Parse it into a `Date` object and then the format is irrelevant. You can do your calculations. Then if you need to display it again, output it in the right format. Specific formats are only for humans. Computers don't use them or care about them when processing dates.

Comment: Anyway it's unclear why the solutions in the question you linked to didn't work for you. Perhaps if you post the code you tried, we can help you to fix it.

Comment: Have you looked into a DateTime library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: How is Feb 28 two months from Dec 30? What is your definition of a month?

Comment: We need a [mcve] !

Comment: The code as shown doesn't work. Please take your time and fix the code, provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @ADyson I have added the code and my output

Comment: I wrote a snippet to parse your date format for you, but when I add two months to that date I get `March 2`, Two months from Dec 30 seems it should be two days after Feb 28, which indeed is March 2.

Comment: @Paulpro you are right about 2 months. Can you share snipet?

Comment: The return value of the `Date.setMonth()` function is the amount of milliseconds between `1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC` and the new date (aka a UNIX timestamp). Perhaps you want to alert `date` instead, which is the modified date object (in the format of a date, rather than UNIX) . That said, your code doesn't work because your original date is invalid.

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer. Please note that I recommend always using the ISO 8601 date format (2018-12-30) for several reasons: 1) Supports leap seconds 2) Supports timezone information 3) Supports milliseconds, or more broadly any amount of precision desired. 4) Lexicographically sorting ISO date strings that are using the same timezone is the same as chronologically sorting the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse that date string into `year`, `month_index`, and `day` components so that you can use the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with them, add the two months using Date methods, and then format it back into a string:

```js
const input = '30-Dec-2018';

console.log( add_two_months( input ) );

function add_two_months ( input ) {
  const date = parse_date_string( input ); 
  date.setMonth( date.getMonth( ) + 2 );
  return format_date( date );
}

// Expects input in form '30-Dec-2018'
function parse_date_string ( str ) { 
  const [ , day, month_str, year ] = input.match( /(\d*)-(\w*)-(\d*)/ );

  const month_index = { 
    jan: 0,
    feb: 1,
    mar: 2,
    apr: 3,
    may: 4,
    jun: 5,
    jul: 6,
    aug: 7,
    sep: 8,
    oct: 9,
    nov: 10,
    dec: 11,
  }[ month_str.toLowerCase( ) ];

  return new Date( year, month_index, day );
}

function format_date ( date ) {
  const day = date.getDate( ).toString( ).padStart( 2, '0' );
  
  const month = [
    'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
  ][ date.getMonth( ) ];
  
  const year = date.getFullYear( );
  
  return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
}
```

If you used the ISO 8601 date/time format, which I highly recommend for several reasons, this could all be reduced to:

```js
const input = '2018-12-30';

console.log( add_two_months( input ) );

function add_two_months ( input ) {
  const date = new Date( input );
  date.setMonth( date.getMonth( ) + 2 );
  return date.toISOString( ).substr( 0, 10 );
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza You're welcome

Comment: This answer doesn't tell the OP why they have their issue.