# check if date difference is exactly X months

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to inform the client of his `Startuday` holyday. The `Startuday` begins on `person.birthday - 9 months`.

Having the *person.birthday*, we need to know if *today* is his `Startuday`?

Is there a more elegant/short way to find the date difference in months than the following:

```js
const today = new Date();
const DeltaMonths = 9;

const person = {
  name: 'John',
  birthday: new Date(
    today.getFullYear(),
    today.getMonth() + DeltaMonths,
    today.getDate()  //-2 // uncomment to see the diff
  )};

let futureDate = new Date(
    today.getFullYear(),
    today.getMonth() + DeltaMonths,
    today.getDate());

let diff = person.birthday - futureDate;

if (diff === 0)
  console.log("Horray %s! Today is your startuday!!!", person.name);
else 
  console.log("Sorry %s, today is NOT yet your startuday...", person.name);
```

Comment: what's exactly nine months before halloween ?  40 weeks might be a better measure - it's what doctors use.

Comment: @Jasen the business requirement was "9 months", take a look here https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=19&m1=10&y1=2022&type=add&ay=&am=9&aw=&ad=&rec=

Comment: What's the business requirement if today is the 31st but there's no 31st in the month 9 months ago? For example, for 31st of January or similarly for 29th or 30th of November?

Comment: "date difference in months" is somewhat ill-defined, ask for clarification

Comment: @Jasen this one is OK https://stackoverflow.com/a/13633692/961631

Answer (score 0):

This should work the same as your code above if I'm understanding it correctly

```
const deltaMonths = 9;

const birthday = new Date('2023-07-19');
const today = new Date();

today.setMonths(today.getMonths() + deltaMonths);

const diff = today.getTime() - birthday.getTime();

const isTheDay = diff >= 0 && diff < (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Comment: Adding months isn't that simple. E.g. Jan 31 plus 1 month will be 2 or 3 March depending on whether it's a leap year. See [*JavaScript function to add X months to a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date).

Comment: @RobG from my understanding of the question, the user's code did what they wanted, they just thought it could be written better. Though from their latest comment, seems like that was not the case.