# How to add months to a date in Office Scripts

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-scripts

I am trying to create a range of dates in TypeScript. I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645058/how-to-add-months-to-a-date-in-javascript). This successfully adds a single increment for a month, but breaks down upon trying to add to the original value again, as it changes the values of both date and addedDate. How would I go about fixing this?
Thanks.

```
const date = new Date("7 December 2023")
const durVal = 10;
for (let i = 0; i < Number(durVal) - 1; i++) {
  let addedDate = date;
  addedDate = new Date(addedDate.setMonth(addedDate.getMonth()+i));
  console.log(addedDate)
}
```

The output is:
"2023-12-06T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-12-07T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-12-08T13:00:00.000Z"..."2026-12-06T13:00:00.000Z"

I would expect the code to increment the month upwards by 1 each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assigning `let addedDate = date` does NOT create a new date object instance. It makes `addedDate` reference to the original `date` variable. So if you modify `addedDate`, it will also change `date` variable coz they reference the same object.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // it is not a typo, `11` stands for Dec.
  const dateStart = new Date(2023, 11, 7); // Dec. 7, 2023, 
  const durVal = 4;
  // Option 1
  let addedDate = new Date(dateStart);
  // Option 2
  // let addedDate = new Date();
  // addedDate.setFullYear(dateStart.getFullYear(), dateStart.getMonth(), dateStart.getDate());
  console.log(dateStart.toDateString() + " <<START>> " + addedDate.toDateString());
  for (let i = 0; i < Number(durVal) - 1; i++) {
    addedDate.setMonth(addedDate.getMonth() + 1);
    console.log(dateStart.toDateString() + " <> " + addedDate.toDateString())
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou. Is there a way to set the variable to have a duplicate value to the original without having it modify the other pointer?