# Adding 4 months to a selected date in dojo and displaying it in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, dojo

In Dojo javascript, after entering from date in a datetextbox , how do I add 4 months to that selected date and display it in a text box?
Any help on this will be valuable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the dojo.date tools:

```
var enteredDate  = myDateTextBox.get("value"),
    modifiedDate = dojo.date.add(enteredDate, "month", 4);

myTextBox.set("value", modifiedDate.toUTCString());
```

This assumes you have `dojo.require("dojo.date");`. Take a look at http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojo/date for an overview of Dojo's date functions.

It's not technically necessary to use Dojo for this at all, though. See this question: [Javascript function to add X months to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date) .