# Add Number of months to a Date in a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function addDays(){ 
      var myDate =document.getElementById('treatdate'); 
      var numberOfDaysToAdd = document.getElementById('resultdays'); 
      var tset = numberOfDaysToAdd.value; 
      var result1 = myDate.value.addMonths(parseInt(tset)); 
      var pldate= moment(result1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      return pldate; }
```

'treatdate' is an id for a treatment date which is pulled from my database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did you need?

Comment: Shouldn't `myDate` be a `Date` in `var result1=`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date ? and even if not, pretty unclearly stated question!

Comment: `var Date = document.getEl....` ???

Comment: I want to add value from id 'resultdays' to a date with id 'treatdate' and return in pldate. It works with new Date() but not with the value from 'treatdate'.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Do you need to retrieve an actual date from your database by id using ajax? Is it the date manipulation that is the problem? Do you need to parse a Date?

Comment: you are using moment.js and still having problems with dates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use moment.js library for Date manipulations. http://momentjs.com/

For your problem you can do the following.

```
function addDays(){
        var datefrmDb = $('#treatdate').val();
        var monthstoadd= $('#resultdays').val();
        var new_date = (moment(datefrmDb, "YYYY-MM-DD").add('months', monthstoadd)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        return new_date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date format is yyyy-MM-dd

```
var myDate = new Date(document.getElementById('treatdate').value);
```

this will a date and time.
**Example:**

```
var dd = new Date("2014-02-02 11:11:11")
```

console log

```
Sun Feb 02 2014 11:11:11 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this snippet can help you understand how to manipulate dates. To change/add the months to a Date() object you can use the setMonth() method.

```
numberOfMonthsToAdd = 5; // the number of months that you want to add
date = new Date(); // creating a Date object
date.setMonth(numberOfMonthsToAdd); // adding the number of months
```

Note that you may add numbers beyond 12 - the object handles the date, and jumps to the next year.