# How to add months to a date of this format?

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

My date is in this format `2008-01-01`(yyyy-mm-dd). I would like to add months to add format such that if I have 2008-01-01 + 13 would give me `2009-02-01`. How can this be done in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function to add X months to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date)

Comment: May I ask why  the negative vote? What is wrong with the question? Please explain so that I can improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date('2008-01-01');
d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + 1 );
alert( d.getFullYear()+'-'+(d.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-'+ d.getDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add months to your date this way.

```
new Date(new Date(myDate).setMonth(myDate.getMonth()+13));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 13);
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. How to I assign `2008-01-01` to `myDate`? Tried `myDate = '2008-01-01';` but it didn't work.

Comment: Found the answer myself. `var myDate = new Date("2008-01-01");`

Answer (score 0):

This is my own answer.

```
var moment = require('moment')
var myDate = new Date("2008-01-01");
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 13);
var answer = moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```