# how to compare current date to a future date and validate it in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

`

`

I have a date text field in mm/dd/yyyy format. When a date is entered, I'd like to validate it to make sure the date is 2 months greater than the current date. If not, I'd like to display a message to notifying the user the date is less then 2 months but user can still proceed with filling the form after the notification.

Below is the form i want to add the function to.

Comment: I recommend you to use the http://momentjs.com library, try it. It makes manipulation of dates easy

Comment: You should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date

Answer (score 0):

If you used javascript then lets try to this one, It may help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDay();
var year = date.getYear();

var newdate = new Date(year,month,day);

mydate=new Date('2011-04-11');

console.log(newdate);
console.log(mydate)

if(newdate > mydate)
{
    alert("greater");
}
else
{
    alert("smaller")
}


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Below is the code where i wish to add that script. Can you help me to modify it using the values i have in it

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format in string then you can use the following method. It will return true if date is 2 months greater than the current date and false otherwise -

```
 // dateString in "mm/dd/yyyy" string format
 function checkMonth(dateString)      
 {
    var enteredMS = new Date(dateString).getTime();
    var currentMS = new Date().getTime();
    var twoMonthMS = new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 2)).getTime();

    if(enteredMS >= twoMonthMS)
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Invoke this as `checkMonth("03/12/2016");`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(d1);

console.log(d1 == d2); // prints false (wrong!) 
console.log(d1 === d2); // prints false (wrong!)
console.log(d1 != d2); // prints true  (wrong!)
console.log(d1 !== d2); // prints true  (wrong!)
console.log(d1.getTime() === d2.getTime()); // prints true (correct)
```

Also you can do <,>,>=,<= etc