# (getDate() - 1) function is getting the value zero if the current date is 1

Tags: javascript, date, netsuite, suitescript

**My Requirement:**

I'm having to fields Start Date and End Date, If the End Date is left empty while saving the record, the End Date Field value is populated with plus 1 year based on the entered from date.

**My Issue:**

If the **Start Date is "9/1/2016"** and the End Date is Left Empty means it should **automatically populate the End Date value as "8/31/2016"** but it **returning the End Date value as "9/0/2016"** and also i'm getting the following **ERROR MESSAGE**

**Error: JS_EXCEPTION
INVALID_FLD_VALUE You have entered an Invalid Field Value Invalid Date for the following field: custrecord_end_date**

**CODE:**
SCRIPT : **CLIENT SCRIPT, EVENT :SaveRecord**

```
function saveRecord(scriptContext) {
  var newRecord= scriptContext.currentRecord;
 var fromDate = new Date(newRecord.getValue('custrecord_created_date'));
 var endDate = newRecord.getValue('custrecord_end_date');
   if (endDate == null || endDate == '') {
    //getting plus 1 year based on the From Date
    tempEndDate = addingPlusYearOfTheCurrentDate(fromDate);

   //setting the value to the End Date Field
     newRecord.setValue('custrecord_end_date', tempEndDate);

}
}
  // Add Plus Year from the Start Date when the End Date is Empty
        function addingPlusYearOfTheCurrentDate(fromDate ) {
            var date = new Date();
            var Month = (fromDate.getMonth() + 1);
            var Dates = (fromDate.getDate() - 1);
            var Year = (fromDate.getFullYear() + 1);
            var last_Day = new Date(Month + '/' + Dates + '/' + Year);


            log.debug('last_Day:', last_Day);
            return last_Day;
        }
```

Comment: isn't it obvious the way you are doing will give you `0` for date

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date

Comment: is there any way to get previous month date(8/31/2016) if the from date is 9/1/2016. thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious - What is the purpose of `var date = new Date();` in `addingPlusYearOfTheCurrentDate()` when you're not using it at all

Comment: @Murugan look at the moment js library. it has lot of good date manipulation functions.

Comment: I love that the title of this question is essentially: why does 1 - 1 = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you expected to be able to subtract 1 from 1 and get anything other than 0, but you can solve this problem by using the `Date` object's `setFullYear()` and `setDate()`.

```js
function addingPlusYearOfTheCurrentDate(fromDate) {
  var date = new Date(fromDate);

  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

  return date;
}

console.log(addingPlusYearOfTheCurrentDate(new Date(2015, 10, 1)));
```

Comment: @RobG You're right. I hadn't looked carefully enough and thought OP had the function returning a string. Didn't notice he was parsing the date all over again. I've changed it to return `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is **strongly** recommended against since parsing is almost entirely implementation dependent and inconsistent. Manually parse strings with a custom function or use a library.

Adding a year to a Date is fairly simple, but it seems you want the date that is one day prior to the same date next year. So add one year then subtract one day.

```js
// Parse m/d/y format string to a Date and validate the result
function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[0]? d : new Date(NaN);
}
   
// Add 1 year to a Date
function addYear(d) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) != '[object Date]') return;
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() -1);
  return d;
}

var d = parseMDY('9/1/2016');
console.log(d.toLocaleString())
addYear(d);
console.log(d.toLocaleString())
```

Note that for 29 February, adding one year gives 1 May, then subtracting one day will give 28 February.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method `nlapiStringToDate()` for string to date conversions, as NetSuite gives date field value as string, which you must convert to date, and before you set back date, you must use `nlapiSetFieldValue(YOUR_FIELD_ID, nlapiStringToDate(dateObject))`

Please see below on suggested usage on reading and setting date fields.

```
function saveRecord(scriptContext) {
  var newRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
  var fromDate = nlapiStringToDate(newRecord.getValue('custrecord_created_date'));
  var endDate = nlapiStringToDate(newRecord.getValue('custrecord_end_date'));
  if (endDate == null || endDate == '') {
    //getting plus 1 year based on the From Date
    tempEndDate = addingPlusYearOfTheCurrentDate(fromDate);

   //setting the value to the End Date Field
     newRecord.setValue('custrecord_end_date', nlapDateToString(tempEndDate));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a 1.0 or 2.0 script?

NetSuite's 1.0 API offers a couple date manipulation methods that might be helpful to you here: `nlapiAddMonths` and `nlapiAddDays`, as well as the Date-String conversion methods.

Here's an example of what you could do in 1.0

```js
// 1.0 API does not pass scriptContext to saveRecord
function saveRecord() {

    // Use nlapiStringToDate instead of raw Date constructor
    var fromDate = nlapiStringToDate(nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_created_date'));

    // Instead of the full extra conditional, just use || as fallback
    var endDate = nlapiStringToDate(nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_end_date')) ||
            calculateEndDate(fromDate);

    // setting the value to the End Date Field
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_end_date', nlapiDateToString(endDate));
}

/** @param fromDate {Date} */
function addYear(fromDate) {
    return nlapiAddMonths(fromDate, 12);
}

/** @param fromDate {Date} */
function dayBefore(fromDate) {
    return nlapiAddDays(fromDate, -1);
}

/** @param startDate {Date} */
function calculateEndDate(startDate) {

    // add 1 year first, then subtract one day
    return dayBefore(addYear(startDate));
}
```

If you're using 2.0 just add a comment, and I will try to update the example if I can. If you've got any questions about how this works, feel free to let me know as well.

Comment: Yes Erict, It is SuiteScript 2.0 version.

Comment: Ah; unfortunately those date APIs don't yet exist in 2.0. You could consider adding [`moment`](http://momentjs.com/) and using its date manipulation APIs, which are incredibly powerful. You will also want to look at the `N/format` module for transforming `String`s to `Date`s and vice-versa