# Get current date + x Months in Epoch format

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime, epoch

For the validation of a form i need to calculate the current date + 3 months and compare it to the value THE client inputted in the form.

Hoe to retrieve the current date plus 3 months in epoch.

I know i retrieve the current date by : (new Date).getTime()

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function to add X months to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution:

```
(new Date).setMonth((new Date).getMonth()+3
```

this wil generate the epoch month with three months from the current date!