# how to calculate date from difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to calculate date from difference and I cant make it work.

I use this code:

```js
$('#TextBox1, #TextBox2').on('input', function() {
  getdate();
});

function getdate() {
  var month = $('#TextBox1').val();
  var num_month = $('#TextBox2').val();

  var date = new Date(month);
  var newdate = new Date(date);

  newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);

  var dd = newdate.getDate();
  var mm = newdate.getMonth() + num_month;
  var yyyy = newdate.getFullYear();

  var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  $('#TextBox3').val(someFormattedDate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Date From :
  <input type="date" id="TextBox1" />
</p>
<p>Difference :
  <input type="number" id="TextBox2" />
</p>
<p>Date To :
  <input type="date" id="TextBox3" />
</p>
```

First input field I set the date, and then the second field I want to enter a number and add that number to the month. and then the third input field will show the calculated output.

for example, I put 11/29/2018 on the first input field and then I type 3 on the second input field. third input field must show 1/29/2019. because 11 is November plus 3 months will be equal to January.

Comment: I believe you can refer , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at momentjs.

Comment: Or `time.js` https://github.com/zackdever/time

Comment: please provide example answer needed from the question

Comment: Be careful of leap years. Tring to roll your own date code is hard, thats why there are libraries for this