# How can I show the next month when my present month is Dec of any year ? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is my Code. My question is how can I show the next month when my current month is Dec.

```
var monthNames = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

 console.log(monthNames[new Date().getMonth()].toString().substr(0, 3) + '-' + new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2));

console.log(monthNames[new Date().getMonth()+1].toString().substr(0, 3) + '-' + new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2));

 console.log(monthNames[new Date().getMonth()+2].toString().substr(0, 3) + '-' + new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2));

  console.log(monthNames[new Date().getMonth()+3].toString().substr(0, 3) + '-' + new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2));

 console.log('Suppose if the current month is Dec-19 then what should I do? It should return next line as Jan-20 but it is not doing so');
```

This is my JSFIDDLE [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qase6bwc)

If my month is Dec 17 or Dec 18 how can I show the next month ? I need a vanilla JS solution, no jQuery, no lodash, no 3rd party libraries.

Comment: add one to month in the date object... date object does the rest for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date

Comment: have a look to the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()). just add an offset and take the result with the remainder operator with the length of the array.

Comment: @Nina Scholz can you kindly show me ? I can't understand. If month is Dec 18 next month will be Jan 19. If current Month is Nov 18 , month + 2 should give me Jan 19

Comment: why not the same day?

Comment: @JaromandaX can you show me ?

Comment: `dateobject.setMonth(dateobject.getMonth() + 1)` - of course ... you're not doing that currently so that won't help much

Comment: @Nina Scholz I can't get your point. I need to show month, next month, 2nd next month along with year. I don't need to show date and day

Comment: @JaromandaX can you show me in my small fiddle ?

Comment: @JaromandaX how can I get year if my present month is Dec and I need to show month + 2 along with year

Answer (score 1):

**Use the date object, and it's built in functions**. Take a vow now to never create an array of month names! `setMonth()` happily takes values greater than 12, or negative values, so just do what you need...

```js
var myDate = new Date('2019-12-19')
myDate.setMonth( myDate.getMonth()+1 )
var formatted = myDate.toLocaleDateString({},{month:'long',year:'2-digit'})
console.log(formatted)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this one will be enough

```
monthNames[(new Date().getMonth() % 12)]
```