# How to change the format of full date

Tags: javascript

Actually I made a function in which picks up the current date. Now i want to pickup the date after 6 months of my current date

```
 var today = new Date();
            var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy ; //Here I am getting current date now i want to get the date exact after 6 months in the same format like this
 var CurrentDate = new Date();
var month=CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 6);//here I am getting date after 6 months but it is in different format like complete date, I want date after after 6 months like above format
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function to add X months to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date)

Comment: It is not duplicate...read my problem again

Comment: 60*24*60*60*1000 << will give you miliseconds of 60 days, this you can add to your current timestamp.

Comment: actually i m getting the date after 6 months i m jut asking for help to change the format

Comment: @chauhanamit i didn't understand

Comment: new Date().getTime() + 60*24*60*60*1000 << will be the timestamp of 60th day from current date.

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
            var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
            var date=today;
            var x = 6; //or whatever offset
            var CurrentDate = new Date();
            //alert(CurrentDate);
            CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + x);
            var d = String(CurrentDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var m = String(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            var yy = CurrentDate.getFullYear();
            CurrentDate = m + '/' + d + '/' + yy;
            var months=CurrentDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass new generated `timestamp` in `new Date()` and it will give you new date

Like `var today_after_month = new Date(timestamp);`

```js
var today = new Date();
            var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            var today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy ; //Here i m getting current date now i want to get the date exact after 6 months in the same format like this
 console.log('today', today);
 var CurrentDate = new Date();
var month=CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 6);//here i m getting date after 6 months but it is different format like complete date i want date after after 6 months like above format

var today_after_month = new Date(month);
 var dd = String(today_after_month.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var mm = String(today_after_month.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            var yyyy = today_after_month.getFullYear();
            var today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy ;
            
 console.log('month', today);
```