# Copy Sheet to new workbook from template based on date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, rename, google-workspace

I have a template sheet inside a workbook that I want to copy to a new workbook that is not yet created. I want this to run on the 29th of each month and do the following:

- Take a Spreadsheet names "Template" and the sheet named “Template..2020.”
- Create a new Spreadsheet called "December 2020" for example, and rename the first tab to 12.01.20, which I can then copy and rename for every day of the month.

I have tried a few copy functions with time triggers but they have required a blank workbook to be open already.

Comment: Please share your current code

Comment: If you need help writing scripts then this might be the place for you. [Google Apps Script Community](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Example Script

This script

- Function `createSheetFromTemplate`

  - Uses the [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get information about today's date and extracts the year, month, day etc.
  - Gets the template from another sheet using [`SpreadsheetApp.openById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
  - Creates a new Sheet based on information from today's date.
  - Copies the template sheet and renames it based on the date.
- Function `createTrigger`

  - Using [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder), creates a trigger to run on the 29th of each month.

Disclaimer: At the moment this script just creates a new Spreadsheet with today's month and a new sheet named with today's date. I understand you may be looking to create a sheet for **next** month. This problem is probably best served by another question - perhaps look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date).

```js
function createSheetFromTemplate() {
  
  // Getting details of today's date
  let date = new Date()
  let year = date.getFullYear()
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1
  let monthName = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
  let day = date.getDate()
  console.log(year, monthName, day)

  // Get template based on year
  let templateSpread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1H7GBVxK4f0nmYR5xfZawy6nreDTCZaj76-dKE9eOtUE")
  let templateSheet = templateSpread.getSheetByName("Template_" + year)
  
  // Create new Spreadsheet with renamed template
  let newSpread = SpreadsheetApp.create(monthName + " " + year)
  let newSheet = templateSheet.copyTo(newSpread).setName(year.toString().substring(2,4) + "." + month + "." + day)
  let sheetToDelete = newSpread.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  newSpread.deleteSheet(sheetToDelete)
}

// Create trigger to run on 29th of each month.
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createSheetFromTemplate')
  .timeBased()
  .onMonthDay(29)
  .create();
}
```

#### References

- [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [`SpreadsheetApp.openById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)