# JavaScript validation for date

Tags: javascript, date, validation, datepicker

I want to validate a date field where only last 12 months or 15 months accepted from today’s date as well for future date from today’s date any JavaScript code for this condition

I used this logic

```
var difference = (date2year*12 +date2month + date2day )-  (date1year*12 +date1month + date1day )
```

&

```
var difference = date2month-date1month +12* (dare2year-date1year)
```

For calculating the difference

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Add or subtract the required number of months from today, then see if the test date is greater than or less than as appropriate. See [*JavaScript function to add X months to a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C457.1322)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the built-in `Date`? You can add/subtract months like this:

```js
const date = new Date(); // Current moment
// Plus 15 months
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 15);
// Minus 15 months
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 15);
```

Situations like 2024/15/11 don't occur (it automatically corrects them). 2024/15/11 will turn into 2025/03/11.

Is it what you want, or I didn't catch your issue?

Answer (score -1):

In such scenarios, I prefer moment.js[Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/), it has many methods to help you play around with date. The in-built Date class in JS is a bit difficult to utilise.

Let's say you want to calculate the difference between today and the given date, say `date1`, with moment we do:

```js
const a = moment(); // today
const b = moment(date1); // given date, can be epoch, ISO, Date, string, etc 
a.diff(b) // this will be a - b and result will be in milliseconds
```

There are several other methods like `between` for your use case, please go through the documentation.
Let me know if you face any difficulty.