# Numeric values not displaying in web page, even though available in server response in jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, formatting, numeric

I am working on a web application that retrieves data from a server using jQuery's `$.ajax()` method and displays the data on a web page. The data includes several numeric values. The values are available in the server response, but they are not displaying in the web page. Specifically, the values for `I` and `J` are not displaying, even though the values for other fields are displaying correctly.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var xyzToggleValue = <%= xyzEnabled %>;
function displayData(cDate) {
  let defPk = $("#defPk").val();
  let ghiId = $("#ghiPK").val().split("=")[0];
  var jklText = $('#jklRange').text();
  var dates = jklText.split(' - ');
  var mnoDate = convertDateFormat(dates[0]);
  var pqrDate = convertDateFormat(dates[1]);

  let dataUrl = "e/data-url?ghiId=" + ghiId + "&defPk=" + defPk + "&mnoDate=" + mnoDate + "&pqrDate=" + pqrDate + "&cDate=" + cDate;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: dataUrl,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            let obj = data[0];
            let dataHtml = '';
            dataHtml += '<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow-x:none;overflow-y:none;"><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">A</span></b>: ' + obj.dA + '<br><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">B</span></b>: ' + obj.oO + '<br><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">C</span></b>: ' + obj.pO + '<br><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">D</span></b>: ' + obj.rO + '<br><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">E</span></b>: ' + obj.pA + '<br><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">F</span></b>: ' + obj.ruA + '<br><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">G</span></b>: ' + obj.pbA + '<br><br>';
            dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">H</span></b>: ' + obj.ruAO + '<br><br>';
            if (xyzToggleValue === "true") {
                dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">I</span></b>: ' + obj.pER.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) + '<br><br>';
                dataHtml += '<b><span class="black">J</span></b>: ' + obj.rER.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) + '<br><br>';
            }
            dataHtml += '</div>';

            // Update the HTML table row with the data
            $('#dataHtml').html(dataHtml);
        }
    },
    error: function(response) {
      $("#errorMsg").html(response.responseText);
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

When I inspect the web page using the browser's developer tools, I can see that the values for **obj.pER** and **obj.rER** are numbers, and they have the correct values. It's just that the values are not displaying on the web page.

The values for are mostly like this

**22,949

8,095**
there could be decimals in this number
**397,150.21

521,702.17**

*I think there is some problem with number formatting*

Comment: I am unable to see any issue: https://jsfiddle.net/so8wakdL/. Could you pls share the `console.log(obj.pER)` value in your Ajax code?

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant when I add a breakpoint on if (data != null && data.length > 0) { there is a value in obj.PER and obj.RER

but its not displaying here

Comment: If it's just your I and J values, then most likely this condition fails: `if (xyzToggleValue === "true") `

btw.. you are comparing it to a string value `"true"` instead of boolean `true`

Comment: @jessiepinkman  I am agreed with the comment of toffler. Recheck that too. it seems like condition needs to be `if (true == xyzToggleValue)`