# Check if date is greater than 6 months past

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, luxon

I am trying to check if a date is greater than 6 months past. For example, today is November 7th, 2023. So if I passed the date of May 10, 2023 I would expect it to only return 5 months because it has not yet been 6 months, but it is currently returning 6 months. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
export const diffInMonths = (date: string) => {
   const dateDifference = parseInt(
     DateTime.fromISO(date).diff(DateTime.now(), ['months']).toFormat('M')
   );

   return dateDifference;
};

//this currently returns -6, when in actuality it should be -5 because it has not been 6 months    yet
console.log(diffInMonths('2023-05-10T20:15:00Z'));
```

Comment: You can make a new Date instance, then use `.setMonth()` to set it's month 6 months in the past, and then see if your date being tested is less than that.

Comment: Is this using Luxon?

Comment: It has been 181 days since 2023-05-10 (writing this on 2023-11-07). You want to know "is the month of the year 6 ago?" The dates you provided are 181 days apart, or 6 months. Diff: https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=05&d1=10&y1=2023&m2=11&d2=7&y2=2023

Comment: @RossAllen yes I am using luxon

Comment: A month is not a fixed unit of time, so you'll need an algorithm for determining whether or not a date is "greater than 6 months ago". You will have to determine the correct implementation for your use case.

Comment: Note that the answer that you selected as "correct" was plagiarized from ChatGPT, and I would view its content with extreme suspicion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels really? how did you find that out? That's insane

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77441695/check-if-date-is-greater-than-6-months-past?noredirect=1#comment136527959_77441695) @Cookies The user has a [recent history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993122/webstylepress?tab=answers) of plagiarizing AI-generated content. If you take a look at the answers, you can identify the pattern.

Comment: You can either add 6 months to the test date and see if it's later than today, or subtract 6 months and see if it's earlier than the test date. How to correctly add and subtract months is detailed at [*JavaScript function to add X months to a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date). You can apply the same algorithm using a library.

Comment: @RossAllen — 181 days may or may not be 6 months. E.g. 1 Apr to 1 Oct is 183 or 184 days (depending on whether the last day is inclusive or not).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is caused by rounding to the nearest whole month. If you try to convert to days first, calculate the difference, and then divide it back to get the month should work better. Don't forget to do Math.floor() after converting back to month.

Good luck!